# login_hint / set email as readonly - azure ad b2c

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using the ready to use User Flow available for SignUpIn. I've figure out it's possible to pass the email using the querystring parameter login_hint, but the focus stays on the email field and my customer wants to avoid an additional 'tab' in order to speedup the login process.

I also found a [sample](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/upskilling-on-azure-b2c-custom-policies-adding-a-new-page-to-the-journey-1e66aeadbff3) which splits a login journey in two steps, but I can't find a way to go directly to the second step, as it uses csrf in order to validate the flow started from Azure AD B2C.

Questions:

1-Is it possible to mark email as readonly when passing a value from login_hint querystring parameter?

2-In case question #1 it's not possible, is it possible to set the focus to the password field?

3-using the custom CIAM User Flow, can I go directly to the second assuming I already know the email?

Answer (score 1):

This [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email) shows how.

- Get the login_hint via {OIDC:LoginHint}
- Make a readonly claim
- Copy login_hint to readonly
- Set the readonly as an input claim in the signin/up

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when you're using the unifiedssp page layout (the standard page layout for the signinsignup policy in the starter packs). The control is rendered as a standard textbox even when the ClaimType's UserInputType is Readonly.